# What is the point to make more than one connection to a server?

Tags: node.js, server, hapi.js

> The Server object is the main application container. The server
>   manages all incoming connections along with all the facilities
>   provided by the framework. A server [can contain](http://hapijs.com/api) more than one
>   connection (e.g. listen to port 80 and 8080).

What is the point to make more than one connection to a server? Memory? Speed? Safety?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious use case is when allowing both TLS and non-TLS requests to be routed to the same server. You make 2 connections to the same server, one with a TLS config and the other without.

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new Hapi.Server();

// Receives TLS requests

server.connection({
    port: 443,
    tls: {
        key: ...,
        cert: ...
    }
});

// Requests HTTP requests

server.connection({ port: 80 });

...
```